# Difference of 2 strict inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Can the difference of 2 strict inequalities be a not strict one?

An example : $$ a, b \in \mathbb R, n \in \mathbb N $$
$$ a< n$$
$$b < n$$

their difference is $\ a-b \leq 0$ no?, since $a$ and $b$ can be equal.

Comment: Only if we could do this; all of our problems would be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

From $a<b$ and $c<d$ you *cannot* infer that $a-c<b-d$.
For example $3<100$ and $1<1000$, so $3-1\stackrel?<100-1000$??

Comment: Nor $a-b\le c-d$!!

Comment: So the difference of 2 such inequalities is pointless?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that two numbers $a$ and $b$ are each less than a third number, $n$, doesn't tell us anything about the *relative* size of $a$ and $b$. We may have $a<b$, $b<a$, or $a=b$. Let's make it concrete with some examples.

Let $n=3$, and consider the following three case:

$a=1$ and $b=2$. Here, $a-b<0$.

$a=2$ and $b=1$. Here, $a-b>0$.

$a=1$ and $b=1$. Here, $a-b=0$.

Again, we can't conclude anything about the relative size of $a$ and $b$ given that they're both greater (or lesser) than some third number $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Your two strict inequalities yield nothing for $a-b$ nor $b-a = -(a-b)$. The only valid conclusions are:
$$a + b < n + n = 2n$$
(addition)
$$-a > -n$$
(negation)
$$\lambda a < \lambda n \qquad \forall\ \lambda > 0$$
(scaling)

Adding $-a > -n$ and $b < n$ gives no relation for $b-a$ because the inequality signs are opposite.